# Angular: Using a Service to communicate data isn't working

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I'm trying to use a service to allow two non-related components to communicate with each other. I'm uncertain how to use @Injectable and providedIn so I think it could be something with that, but eveything online seems to point to that I'm doing it correctly. My code in these files are close to 1000 lines so I removed alot of the code. Sorry if the code has incomplete details, just not trying to include all those line.

Here's the service file where I store the data:

emailService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class EmailFormatService {
  private videoMessage = new BehaviorSubject<string>("False");
  public message = this.videoMessage;

  public setVideoMessage(message: string) {
    console.log("set video");
    this.videoMessage.next(message);
  }

  public getVideoMessage() {
    return this.videoMessage;
  }
}
```

I use the setVideoMessage and getVideoMessage to access the data.
The parent file is where I'm trying to set the data within the service.

parentFile.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
import { MailConfigService } from './mail-config.service';

const CONTEXT = 'MailAddInService';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Parent {
  public constructor(
    private _emailService: EmailFormatService,
  ) {}

  public message?: string;

  public openDialogWindow(
    event: OpenDialogEvent | undefined,
    route: string,
    message?: string,
  ) {
    this._emailService.setVideoMessage("hello");
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
      `${this._mailConfigService.environment.verbMail.addInUrl}/index.html#/${route}`,
    );
    }
  }
```

The child file is where I want to get the data. This is where the data is returning the value "False".

childFile.ts

```
public message!: string;

public constructor(
private _emailService: EmailFormatService,
) {

    this._emailService.getVideoMessage().subscribe(vidMessage => {
      this.message = vidMessage;
    });
}
```

childFile.html

```
<div>
 "Hi"
 {{message}}
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is that the getVideoMessage will return "False" even after a set the video message. It's like it's accessing a different instance of the service.

Comment: It looks okay.. so you might indeed have multiple instances. Just add a constructor with a console.log in your service and check if it only creates once..

Comment: @MikeOne I did that and it got two logs so it is getting constructed twice. Could opening a Dialog window cause that to happen? The second log would come when the second window popped up.

Comment: You should check if your `EmailFormatService` is also found in one of your `providers` array and remove it. By the looks of it, you should only have a single instance of this service available in the `root` injector, but if you put it in the `providers` array of a module, this can cause the creation of multiple instances.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I've triple checked, I didn't include EmailFormatService in any providers aray

Comment: `Parent` as well, right? All your services that are `providedIn: 'root'` should not be part of any `providers` array.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I'll double check, but I don't think so. If that's not the issue do you have any other ideas? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I was looking through [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service) in search of an answer, but I did not come up with anything so far. By using the `providedIn: 'root'`, you should only have one instance application wide.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I was able to dig through a bunch of docs and find out why this wasn't working. Basically I was using the office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() which runs on top of the host. This causes all services to be a new instance. Local storage and query parameters can be used for communication instead. Here's a link to the docs where I found these answers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/parent-to-dialog